# Python : add child node through loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

How to add child node through loop? I am using treeView. I have define rows array. In this Primary1,Primary2,Primary3 are parent node. And Secpndary1 child node of Primary1. r[1] defines Primary or secondary and r[2] defines parent node name

```
rows = [('Primary1', 'Primary', None), ('Primary2', 'Primary', None),
        ('Secpndary1', 'Secondary', 'Primary1'),('Primary3', 'Primary', None)]


tree = []

for r in rows:
    tree.append({'node_id': r[1], 'children': []})
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
rows = [('Primary1', 'Primary', None), ('Primary2', 'Primary', None),
    ('Secpndary1', 'Secondary', 'Primary1'),('Primary3', 'Primary', None)]


tree = []

for r in rows:
    if r[2] is None:
        tree.append({'node_id': r[0], 'children': []})
for r in rows:
    if r[2] is not None:
        for node in tree:
            if node['node_id'] == r[2]:
                node['children'].append({'node_id': r[0], 'children': []})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another solution which can work.

```
rows = [('Primary1', 'Primary', None), ('Primary2', 'Primary', None),
        ('Secpndary1', 'Secondary', 'Primary1'),('Primary3', 'Primary', None), ('Secondary2', 'Secondary', 'Primary1')]

from collections import defaultdict
dd = defaultdict(list)
for row in rows:
    node , _ , child = row
    x = dd[child].append(node) if child else dd[node]

print dd

>>> dd
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'Primary2': [], 'Primary3': [], 'Primary1': ['Secpndary1', 'Secondary2']})
```